# Win32 C++ 14/17 - Permanent Painted Cursor on Windows 10 1809 GUI App

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

Hi everyone and thanks for your time and help. I'm investigating a use-case in which I want to permanently paint a cursor onto a GUI application using win32 c++ 14/17 on Windows 10 1809. This would produce multiple "cursors" but really only one system cursor would receive input while the others are simply icons that remain painted in the last cursor position within the GUI app client window. This distinction is incredibly important. I know it's currently not possible to configure multiple active cursors on a single windows session. Here, I'm simply trying to display multiple painted cursors despite only one being active at a time.  If you have any recommendations or advice I'd greatly appreciate it. :-) Thanks in advance!

EDIT: After confusion surfaced over the question I've decided to elaborate on my use-case.

My current use-case is essentially creation of a kiosk setup involving two displays which appear to connect with a completely isolated computer to the user despite running on the same hardware. In order to do so, I've created a message-only window which handles input routing to each display via PostMessage(...). Each display, in turn, has its own message loop which processes the routed input. In this case, I'm tracking coordinates and all is working. But when I use a given input on one display and use a second input device mapped to the second display I see the cursor disappear on the first display and jump to the second display. The goal here is to provide visual feedback (i.e, a cursor) to the user despite jumping to the second display so that the user perceives each monitor as being attached to an independent "computer". This is why I want the cursor to remain painted at the previous known position. Any help and input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the question exactly? Just draw them in `WM_PAINT`...

Comment: @MatteoItalia Wow, thank you for the quick response! How would you recommend stopping them from being hidden? Do you have additional specifics? Thank you, again, for your help. :-)

Comment: @MatteoItalia I'll elaborate on my question. Simply put, when I leave my current GUI the cursor is hidden within that window. What I'd like to do is keep the cursor painted. So, imagine you're focused on a GUI windows app and you're moving your mouse. If you leave that GUI application the cursor within the application disappears because you're moving it out of the window. I would like the painted cursor within that window to remain painted despite being inactive. Does that make more sense? Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: Completly nonsense, if you move cursor, in which position in your window want your painted cursor? At centre ? At border?

Comment: @user2120666 it's not non-sense. If you don't understand how to answer the question that's perfectly fine but I'd appreciate constructive and helpful responses. :-) I track the previous cursor position in a message-only window. I literally want the cursor image (i.e, an arrow) showing up at the last hit point in the client window so the main hurdle isn't which (x, y) pair but rather how do I keep the cursor from being hidden on leaving the window.

Comment: Hello! Please add further details in the question, dont'leave them in the comments. It's easy to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Will do, @Valentino. I'll add some more use-case-specific information

Comment: If I move cursor from your window to another, last position in your client area is near border. Is this what you want?

Comment: @user2120666 thanks for asking. That's not necessarily always the case (i.e, when a tablet is used only discrete clicks are tracked (we're excluding multi-touch support here). So, the point can be anywhere on a given rectangle not just at the border. :-)

Comment: I understand this, also changing foreground window using keyboard is possible. I think that one possibilty is handling WM_MOUSEMOVE, remember position, draw cursor at WM_PAINT as pointed by Matteo Italia

Comment: @user2120666 that's a good idea. I'll try it out. I think it may not work when using a message-only window as the parent due because I'm not receiving WM_PAINT messages. But it's definitely worth a shot! I'm also looking at using the device context to draw without use of WM_PAINT as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawicon . It's interesting stuff!

Comment: I have done similar things in the past (where two apparently separate systems run off the same PC) and I found the best solution was to hide the system cursor altogether and simulate each screen's cursor entirely myself. You can use DirectInput to identify which input device (touch screen presumably) your input is coming from.

Comment: @JonathanPotter thank you for the response! That's actually how I'm approaching things at the moment but one major remaining "feature" is getting the simulated cursors to "permanently" display. Do you have any resources that you used or recommendations on how to achieve that? Right now it sounds like using the method you suggested is best + use of GetDC(...) and DrawIcon(...). But there's some uncertainty in that.

Comment: Simulate mouse pointer with window. Non rectangular shape can be achieved with `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` (or `SetWindowRgn`). To make it topmost use `SetWindowPos` with `HWND_TOPMOST`. `GetCursorInfo` and `GetCursor` provide information needed to replicate cursor appearance.

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot of good ideas and responses to this question. What I ended up doing was using DrawIcon(...) to draw the icon directly on the screen location. However, it turns out part of the reason I wasn't observing the cursor being drawn was because I re-created the desktop window instead of grabbing the window from the RECT returned by EnumDisplayMonitors(...). So, I was drawing against the wrong window object. So the problem was solved by...

- Ensuring I'm grabbing the correct window object associated with the desktop.
- Hiding the system cursor and drawing my simulated cursor using DrawIcon(...)

Thank you for all the answers. I hope this can help someone else hitting the same sort of problem. :-)